# send variable from controller to a view

Tags: symfony

i have a problem in my project
i want to send a variable from a controller to a view.
in the action i want to get the id of the current user (i'm using the FOSUserBundle) then search in notification table for the number of notification of that user.
in the end i want to send the number to a view.
but i always get this error "Variable "notificationN" does not exist.".
what should i do?
this the action:

```
public function notificationNumberAction(){
        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $user->getId();
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM notification WHERE userId=".$user.";";

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $n=$stmt->execute();

        return $this->render('EnigmaSocialProBundle::layout.html.twig',array("notificationN"=>$n));
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the code of layout.html.twig?

Comment: it's a long long file but i'm calling the variable with {{ notificationN }}

Comment: Sorry but without the twig I don't see anything wrong in what you posted.

Could it be that you have more than one layout.html.twig and it actually is not rendering the one you're expecting (ie. picking the default layout from the bundle Resources folder). It's a long shot, but could you try changing the name of the file and in your render()  call?

Comment: write $n = "test"; in first line of your function, and tell us what says your template

Comment: you are sending your user object , not his id by the way

Comment: i tried the $n="test" and nothing chaned

Comment: @Strnm i have only one layout file
and the file is too long (447 lines)
i'm sure the problem is with the action, probably with the way i'm getting the id of the user and how i send it

Answer (score 0):

You can access user data directly in the twig template without requesting anything in the controller. The user is accessible like that : app.user.

You can do :

```
{% if is_granted("ROLE") %}
    Hi {{ app.user.username }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution

```
$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()
```

doesn't work with symfony3, now i only need to $this->getUser() to get the current user

the new action is:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
        $user->getId();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $stmt = $em->createQueryBuilder('n')->select('COUNT(n)')->from('EnigmaSocialProBundle:Notification','n')
            ->where('n.userId = :p')->setParameter('p',$user);
        $n=$stmt->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```